# Google Spreadsheets: Formula to "interleave" or "zipper" multiple arrays

Tags: google-sheets

Tried searching and checking Google documentation but I am still having issues getting the results that I want for this problem.

I'm needing to split several comma-separated lists of items and recombine them so that first items in each list is combined, followed by the second item, etc.

To ask with an illustration, if I have a cell with the following

```
Paul, John, George, Ringo
```

and another cell with the following

```
McCartney, Lennon, Harrison, Starr
```

How do I use one function to produce this in a cell?

```
Paul McCartney, John Lennon, George Harrison, Ringo Starr
```

Comment: Are the two starting fields adjacent or stacked on top of each other alternating? Also are there always the same number of fields in every cell? e.g. 4 values to be split and rejoined?

Comment: The two starting fields are adjacent. For added clarification, they are comma-separated strings in two adjacent cells--we can pretend the first names are in A1 and the last names are in B1. The count of the items produced by a SPLIT is guaranteed to be the same in A1 as in B1.

Comment: See the solution below. If you have any questions let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, you will need to copy to every row - but assuming your data is in columns A and B it will work across a dynamic number of items:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(join(",",split(A1,",")&" "&split(B1,",")))
```

See image example below, in row one i used the data you showed up top, and in row two i reversed the column data just to show as an example:

[image]

Comment: Ah, that'll do it! Looks like the gap in my understanding was coming from how ARRAYFORMULA modifies the formula. Here are the docs for anyone that needs it like I did: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en

Comment: Most often one would use arrayformula down a column but  unfortunately split is  one of the few it doesn't work with vertically, howeverit does horizontally

Answer (score -1):

If you paste the first word CSV to Sheet1 and the second word CSV to Sheet2 then you could put the following into sheet3

In Cell A1:

```
=Sheet1!A1&" "&Sheet2!A1
```

This is saying take the value in sheet1 A1 and then a space `" "` then the value in sheet2 A1

You could also do this with the concatenate function:

```
=CONCATENATE(Sheet1!A1," ",Sheet2!A1)
```

Then just copy the formula to suit.